# Mensagem de feedback em formulário de contato php

Tags: php, formulário

Boa noite, tenho um formulário de contato que está funcionando perfeitamente.
Porém, após enviar o email, a página fica branca e não tenho uma mensagem de feedback.
Eu gostaria de exibir uma modal com a mensagem.
Segue o meu código:

```
<?php    
$nome = $_POST['nome'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$cpf = $_POST['cpf'];
$moeda = $_POST['moeda'];
$valor = $_POST['valor'];
$local = $_POST['local'];
$formcontent=" Nome: $nome \n Email: $email \n CPF: $cpf \n Moeda: $moeda \n Valor: $valor \n Local: $local";
$recipient = "nome@exemplo.com";
$subject = "Contato Delivery SP";
$mailheader = "From: $email \r\n";
mail($recipient, $subject, $formcontent, $mailheader) or die("Error!");

if ($formcontent == 1){ 
  echo "<script>$('#form-modal').modal('show')</script>"; 
}else{
  echo "<script>$('#form-modal-2').modal('show')</script>"; 
} 

?>
```

Comment: Tá, mas o que te impede de fazer isso? Cadê o código do modal? É bootstrap? JQuery UI?

Comment: @user5978 Sim. Bootstrap. A modal está certinha na página index.php, eu consigo chamar ela pelo console normalmente. Só que na hora de enviar o formulário, ao invés de abrir a modal, abre a página em branco do sendmail.php (que é a página com esse código aí de cima)...

Comment: Mas onde está esse modal? no formulário? Quando você envia dados via formulário (sem ajax) o conteúdo da página é "perdido". Coloca o HTML do modal (e a inclusão da biblioteca relacionada e dependências) acima do <?php... do código que você postou. Creio que ai vá funcionar ...

Comment: Essa linha aqui não tem muito sentido. `if ($formcontent == 1){ ` - Com certeza nunca vai ser um, pois é o texto da mensagem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se você diz que está sendo exibido uma tela em branco, imagino que você não esteja utilizando AJAX. Nesse caso, você deve ter em mente que o conteúdo da página onde está o formulário, após envio é totalmente "redefinido".

Você deve acrescentar isso no código

```
<!-- Inclusão das bibliotecas-->
<link rel....bootstra.css
<scr...bootstrap.js
<scr...jquery.js

<!-- código dos modals(ou ais) -->
<div class="modal-1"..
 ......
<div class="modal-2...
 ......

<!-- Aqui vai o script que você postou -->
<?php    
$nome = $_POST['nome'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$cpf = $_POST['cpf'];
$moeda = $_POST['moeda'];
...
```

Comment: obrigada!!!! :)