# Formulário de Contato com dados em branco

Tags: php

Tenho um formulário de contato num site que fiz, porém o email está vindo com os campos do form em branco. Alguém pode me ajudar?

O e-mail chega tudo certo porém o valor dos `$_POST["nome"]` está vindo em branco.

```
<?php
header('Content-type: application/json');

$status = array(
    'type'=>'success',
    'message'=>'Mensagem enviada com sucesso!'
);

$nome = $_POST['nome'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$telefone = $_POST['telefone'];
$mensagem = $_POST['mensagem'];

$email_from = $email;
$email_to = 'informatica@tecnova.ind.br';


$body = 'Nome: ' . $nome . "\n\n" . 'Email: ' . $email . "\n\n" . 'Telefone: ' . $telefone . "\n\n" . 'Mensagem: ' . $mensagem;

$success = @mail($email_to, $subject, $body, 'From: <'.$email_from.'>');


echo json_encode($status);
die;

<form id="main-contact-form" class="contact-form" name="contact-form" method="POST" action="sendemail.php">
              <div class="row-fluid">
                <div class="span5">
                    <label>Nome</label>
                    <input type="text" id="nome" name="nome" class="input-block-level" required="required">
                    <label>Email</label>
                    <input type="email" class="input-block-level" required="required" id="email" name="email">
                    <label>Telefone</label>
                    <input type="text" class="input-block-level" required="required" id="telefone" name="telefone">
                </div>
                <div class="span7">
                    <label>Mensagem</label>
                    <textarea name="mensagem" id="mensagem" required="required" class="input-block-level" rows="8" style="height: 222px;"></textarea>
                </div>

            </div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-large pull-right">Enviar mensagem</button>
            <p> </p>

        </form>
```

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Mensagem de feedback em formulário de contato php](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/125288/mensagem-de-feedback-em-formul%c3%a1rio-de-contato-php)

Comment: Você está separando o form do php?

Comment: no caso dele, ele quer que aparece um modal com mensagem enviada. No meu caso, o e-mail chega tudo certo, porém os valores recebidos no $_POST["nome"] está vindo em branco

Comment: sim, estão em arquivos separados

Comment: Acabei de testar o seu código e está funcionando

Comment: Aqui pra mim o email chega da seguinte forma...

Nome: 

Email: 

Telefone: 

Mensagem:

Comment: dá um var_dump($_POST) para ver o que retorna

Comment: A página `sendemail.php` só tem o código PHP acima ou tem mais outra coisa?

Comment: só tem o código php acima

Comment: o que retornou no var_dump?

Comment: retornou NULL..

Comment: estou desconfiando que é o servidor do cliente. tem chance de ser?